# .NET RegEx.Replace substring with special chars

Tags: c#, .net, regex, replace

I use the following to replace a word in a string

```
Regex.Replace("C1", @"\bC1\b", "'test $'", RegexOptions.None);
```

Result is:

```
"'test "
```

But I'd expect it to be

```
"' test $'"
```

So basically the regexp method also interprets the replacement string, instead of using it "as is". I tried all `RegexOptions` without luck.

What is the suggested approach to ensure the replacement string is inserted exactly as is?

Comment: Replace with `"'test $$'"`, `RegexOptions` have got nothing to do here.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew are there any other characters that need special care?? I mean, e.g. "\", ".", and so on...?

Comment: No, I do not think so.